# Why do I get "can't convert String into Integer" when accessing a JSON object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-test

I have a JSONString in key-value pair format, and, in my test, I am trying to verify the value for a particular key in the string using:

```
JSONString['key'] should eq 'value'
```

My value is a string like a person's name, like `John` or `Jenny`.

After executing, I get this error:

```
Can't convert String into Integer for the mentioned code.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Chances are you have an Array instead of the type you think you have.

Comment: `inspect` `JSONString`. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

`JSONString` is an array object, that's why you are getting this exception.

Example:

```
1.9.3p392 :001 > a = [1,2]

1.9.3p392 :002 > a['xyz']

TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
```